# Is it possible to promote a soldier twice in one mission?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

If I take a rookie/squaddie solider on a long mission and he gets lots of kills - will he receive XP to take him up 2 levels - or am I always 'capped' to one promotion per mission?

edit: same for Psi skills - if one guy does lots of Psi skills - can he get a double promotion - or am I wasting my time?

Comment: I can't confirm it 100%, but it seems to me it's capped. I've had some rookies on the alien base mission, and they each got only one promotion.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have never seen a double promotion (other than somebody getting a psi promotion and a regular promotion, which is quite common), despite engineering situations where a single operative gets to use Mindfray a dozen times in a mission or kill 9 thin men with a single blaster charge. It would seem that the answer is no, you can't get double promotions.

Comment: There's still a question - is extra experience ignored and lost, then, or does it just carry over to the next mission and you get a promotion for free?

Comment: I just tested this - took a squaddie on a mission - he killed 5x guys - only one promotion

Comment: and there was no white "+" on any of my guys at the beginning of the next mission - so I dont think it carries over

Comment: A comment [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/88987/what-do-the-icons-next-to-a-soldiers-rank-icon-mean#comment125958_88988) also suggests that you shouldn't waste potential kill-XP on a unit that already has a white cross